# Reading unicode from console

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, console

I am trying to read unicode string from a console in C#, for the sake of example, lets uset his one:

**c:\SVN\D³ebugger\src\виталик\Program.cs**

At first I just tried to `Console.ReadLine()` which returned me `c:\SVN\D3ebugger\src\???????\Program.cs`

I've tried to set the Console.InputEncoding to UTF8 like so `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8` but that returned me `c:\SVN\D³ebugger\src\???????\Program.cs`, basically mucking up the Cyrillic part of the string.

So randomly stumbling I've tried to set the encoding like that, `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);` which returned `c:\SVN\D?ebugger\src\виталик\Program.cs`, this time corrupting the ³ character.

At this point it seems that by switching [encodings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195051.aspx) for the InputStream I can only get a single language at a time.

I've also tried going native and doing something like that:

```
// Code
public static string ReadLine()
{
    const uint nNumberOfCharsToRead = 1024;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    uint charsRead = 0;
    bool result = ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buffer, nNumberOfCharsToRead, out charsRead, (IntPtr)0);

    // Return the input minus the newline character
    if (result && charsRead > 1) return buffer.ToString(0, (int)charsRead - 1);
    return string.Empty;
}

// Extern definitions

    [DllImport("Kernel32.DLL", ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern bool ReadConsoleW(IntPtr hConsoleInput, [Out] StringBuilder lpBuffer, 
        uint nNumberOfCharsToRead, out uint lpNumberOfCharsRead, IntPtr lpReserved);
```

That was working fine for non-unicode strings, however, when I tried to make it read my sample string, the application crashed. I've tried to tell Visual Studio to break on ALL exception (including native ones), yet, the application would still crash.

I also found [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652017/bcl-reading-unicode-input-from-console-not-supported) open bug in Microsoft's Connect that seems to say that it is impossible right now to read Unicode from the console's InputStream.

It is worth noting, even though not strictly related to my question, that Console.WriteLine is able to print this string just fine, if Console.OutputEncoding is set to UTF8.

Thank you!

## Update 1

I am looking for a solution for .NET 3.5

## Update 2

Updated with the full native code I've used.

Comment: Is it possible/acceptable to use a named pipe instead of the console?

Comment: If I don't find a solution then that's probably what I'll do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one fully working version in .NET 3.5 Client:

```cs
class Program
{
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  static extern bool ReadConsoleW(IntPtr hConsoleInput, [Out] byte[]
     lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfCharsToRead, out uint lpNumberOfCharsRead,
     IntPtr lpReserved);

  public static IntPtr GetWin32InputHandle()
  {
    const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
    IntPtr inHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    return inHandle;
  }

  public static string ReadLine()
  {
    const int bufferSize = 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    uint charsRead = 0;

    ReadConsoleW(GetWin32InputHandle(), buffer, bufferSize, out charsRead, (IntPtr)0);
    // -2 to remove ending \n\r
    int nc = ((int)charsRead - 2) * 2;
    var b = new byte[nc];
    for (var i = 0; i < nc; i++)
      b[i] = buffer[i];

    var utf8enc = Encoding.UTF8;
    var unicodeenc = Encoding.Unicode;
    return utf8enc.GetString(Encoding.Convert(unicodeenc, utf8enc, b));
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Console.Write("Input: ");
    var st = ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Output: {0}", st);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Change bufferSize in ReadLine() if you need big strings. Notice the buffer will take **twice** as much bytes as characters. Also, if you don't mind using Linq, you can use: `var b = buffer.Take(nc).ToArray();` instead of that ugly For loop.

Comment: It worked great, thanks! Though, I did something very similar (using ReadConsoleW) which wouldn't work at all. I'll check what I did wrong and update.

Comment: You probably didn't convert to UTF8 afterwards. Probably the input was ok, but the output wasn't (just guessing)

Comment: I found out what I did wrong thanks to your answer and edited accordingly. It used to be `new StringBuilder()` which worked fine for ANSI but crashed for Unicode. Now when I've initialized it with an initial size - `new StringBuilder(nNumberOfCharsToRead)` it worked fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 14):

This seems to work fine when targetting .NET 4 client profile, but unfortunately not when targetting .NET 3.5 client profile.  Ensure you change the console font to Lucida Console.
As pointed out by @jcl, even though I have targetted .NET4, this is only because I have .NET 4.5 installed.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

        while (true)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(s);

                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you on .NET 4.5, perhaps? It doesn't work in .NET 4.0. The line `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;` throws an exception: "IOException - The parameter is incorrect."

Comment: I do have VS 11 beta and .NET 4.5 beta installed.  However the console app works using VS 2010 and .NET 4 client profile. I'm using Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Comment: I can confirm I get the same exception as you when targetting .NET 3.5 client profile.

Comment: It definitely does not work on .NET 4.0 unless you have installed .NET 4.5. Your target application is using the updated version of mscorlib (for which Microsoft oddly didn't change the version number in the developer preview of .NET 4.5, that's why it's using it even if you are targeting 4.0), which actually explicitly checks for the Unicode codepage to not call SetConsoleCP. The check is not included in the regular mscorlib.dll in 4.0 and that's why it's raising IOException (it does so when SetConsoleCP fails).

Comment: Hi, I am running this is a slave application, and it does not seem to be working for me

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core, I have successfully used this variant (read one keypress at a time as a Unicode character):

```cs
string ReadLineUnicode()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    while (true)
    {
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            break;

        sb.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```