# How to make C# ReadLine() method maintain the same non-english characters?

Tags: c#, string, methods, character

I was making a simple string manipulator. Now I want it to be compatible with my native tongue, which means that my strings will contain such characters as 'ė' or 'ę'. Yet I noticed through the debugger that when I execute this line of code:

```
string word = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
```

the 'ė' and 'ę' are swapped with a regular 'e'. I'm pretty new to C# so I'd like to know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627255/43846 may help

Comment: I think `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`  should to the trick

Comment: @PatrickHofman fixed ,

Comment: That doesn't work @styx

Comment: This *does* work: `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode; Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`